# 正規表現で「タグから閉じタグまで」を探したい。

Tags: 正規表現

以下の場合、どのように正規表現を書いたらよいですか？
100近くhtmlファイルがあり、一気に置換したい目的です。

```
<div class="test">
何かしらタグや文章が入ります。一定ではありません。
<!--コメント-->
</div>
```

追記です。devasというツールで置換の為、特にlinuxとかphpではありません。
失礼しました。

Comment: 何を何に置換したいんですかね？

Comment: <div><div class="test">foo<div>bar</div>baz</div></div> の場合はどこからどこまでマッチすべきでしょうか。

Comment: そうなんですよね。。。上記ですと、最後の</div>まで該当してしまい、たまたま、当方は</div>の前にコメントアウトがあったので、終わりを.*--></div>にして解決できましたので、そのような内容に修正したいと思います。ご指摘すみません。

Comment: 自己解決したのであれば、質問に追記するのではなく自分で回答として投稿し承認してください

Answer (score 2):

ヒントをいただいて、以下で検索でき解決できました。
^で始まる.*（何か間にあって、終わるテキスト・タグを後ろに入れる）

```
^<div class="test">.*--></div>
```